# Erro de conexão com o mysql via socket (e/ou erro de soquete na instalação do MySQL)

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, socket

Ao tentar acessar o Mysql através do prompt usando o comando `mysql -uNOME_USUARIO -p`, recebo a mensagem de erro:

> **ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)**

Mesmo após iniciar/reiniciar o mysql com os comandos abaixo o erro persiste:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Algumas ideias http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Comment: O primeiro comando não funcionou aqui.
usei sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*

Comment: Se estiver usando localhost tente usar 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Estou enfrentando o mesmo problema instalando a versão 5.6 do MySQL no Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Depois de procurar e falar com amigos, descobri como instalar sem erro.

Primeiro, faça backup dos bancos de dados e siga estes comandos:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge *mysql/*
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
$ sudo apt install mysql-server-5.6
$ sudo apt install mysql-client-5.6
```

Comment: O primeiro comando acho que é `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*`

Answer (score 4):

Bem, provavelmente é uma questão relativas as permissões do sistema ou você tem instalado somente o mysql-client, mas não o `mysql-server` e, portanto, não pode criar um arquivo do tipo UNIX Socket.

Então o que você deveria tentar primeiro é instalar o mysql-server:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Se você tem certeza de que o `mysql-server` está instalado, cheque o arquivo de configuraçao principal, que no Debian e Ubuntu deveria está em `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` ou `/etc/my.cnf`. No meu Debian 7 está localizado em `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.
Sua primeira parte do arquivo deveria parecer-se com isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebe que sob [client] há uma chave chamada `socket`? Pois bem, esse é o arquivo unix socket que o mysql usa para conexão local, por padrão (ao menos que você não force para TCP).
Se esse arquivo não existe crie-o:

```
$ sudo touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Se ele existe, tente dá as permissões adequadas e atentando ao grupo de usuários:

```
$ sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Como uma nota final,você também poderia se conectar usando TCP, ao invés de UNIX socket.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda, mas eu já havia solucionado.

Comment: Funcionou pra mim, Server version: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Bom, acho que encontrei o problema, e foi de uma maneira bem simples, como achei o problema, pode ser que ajude outros, então resolvi publicar a resposta:
Primeiro tentei remover a versão corrompida:
`sudo apt-get remove mysql --purge`. Depois ao invés de instalar "**mysql-server-5.5**", apenas digitei:
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`. E para finalizar, ao invés de dar um **start**, o que precisei é **restartar** para definir o inicializador do mysql:
`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Depois disso, ainda precisei restartar o serviço do MySQL pelo comando:
`sudo service mysql restart`

E aí tudo voltou a funcionar...

Answer (score 0):

Me parece ser um erro de atriuição de PATH.

Eu vinha enfrentando este mesmo erro utilizando o LAMPP e a linha de comando, porém quando eu usava a interface PHPmyAdmin, o Mysql funcionava normalmente.

A solução pra mim foi copiar o arquivo de configuração(conf. file) do LAMPP para o arquivo contido em `etc/mysql/my.cnf` e agora a linha de comando acessa o mysql normalmente.

De qualquer forma esta é apenas uma solução paleativa