# Erro: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Nenhuma ligação pode ser feita porque o computador de destino as recusou ativamente

Tags: php, mysql, linux

Estou a tentar aceder através do meu pc a um servidor com linux onde tem instalado o phpmyadmin. Que configurações preciso fazer do lado do servidor para conseguir entar. 
Já experimentei colocar na minha configuração a porta e continua sem funcionar. 
Penso que o problema é mesmo não ter permissões para aceder ao servidor.

Comment: De uma lida nesse tópico: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80031/erro-de-soquete-na-instala%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-mysql